# Identifying and removing features from scanned handwriten text

Tags: image-processing

Please, can I have some ideas and help on how to identify and remove features like this one [image: hand written text feature] or this one [image: hand written text feature] from scanned handwritten text like this:
[image: hand written text sample]
 These features are not connected to other text elements (letters), they are always similar to this two examples, and they are oriented with slight variation (up to +/-10 degrees). They are always below letters. In this example there are 12 such features (4,6,2 in rows 1,2,3).

Comment: Since this is an image processing problem, you need to supply the complete image. Otherwise, there's no way to know how to remove those artifacts: we can't know if you can just remove a color, or if you have to identify shapes, etc. Also: be a little more clear what you need. Do you need to remove *those specific* images, or do you need to remove splotches that are generally that shape and are generally purple like that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Almost!

Convert your image to binary image

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRUEw.jpg"];
binimg = ColorNegate@Binarize[img, .75]
```

[image]

Get tha `mask` used in `Inpaint`

```
mask = SelectComponents[binimg, {"PerimeterLength", "Elongation"}, 
  60 < # < 160 || #2 > 0.8 &]
```

[image]

Contrasting your image with after.

```
Grid[{{"Before", Magnify[img, 5]}, {"After",Magnify[Inpaint[img, Dilation[mask, 1], 
     Method -> "TextureSynthesis"], 5]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: this aproach is useful for me, but I have little problem with function construction. Please help for implementing `MinimalBoundingBox` measure in this:
`Needs["Developer`"];`
`SelectComponents[
 someimage
 , {"MinimalBoundingBox"}
 , 11 > Min@
    PartitionMap[
     EuclideanDistance[_SOME _CODE _HERE _] &, #1[[1 ;; 3]], 2, 1] &
 ]`

Answer (score 3):

## Hey, go to upvote @yode's answer! He's brilliant!

Result first, I hope that would be good enough:

[image: comp]

The idea is quite simple------Find those feature and try to delete them.

---

## How to use the code?

1. Manually select the features you would like to delete, binarize it properly and put it in `ker`. For example, at this place you could use something like this:

[image: ker]

2. If you want a better result, create another mask and roughly single out all the words. Create a mask like this and put it in `msk1`:

[image: msk1]

3. run the code and get the result.

---

## Code

```
Inpaint[imgo, 
 Binarize[ColorSeparate[
   HighlightImage[
    imgo, {Red, Opacity@1, 
     Disk[#, 20] & /@ 
      ImageCorners@
       Binarize[
        ImageCorrelate[
         ImageMultiply[ColorNegate@Binarize@imgo, ColorNegate@msk1], 
         ker, Mean@Abs@Flatten[#1 - #2] &], .2]}], "R"], .95]]
```

---

## How it works

1. Firstly and most importantly, it will do a `ImageCorrelate` and find the points with good fit to ker.
2. Then it will find out those points in need of delete process by using `ImageCorners`
3. Finally, we can use `Inpaint` to get a desired result.

---

## Places that can be further improved

1. The sign MUST BE almost **EXACTLY** the same. longer or shorter will influence the detection process and some extra mark in detection area will also interfere with result. Also, sometimes it will mis-detect the down part of "o" if you don't make the mask carefully.
2. Speed is quite slow......

Hope this can help you~

---

## Edit 1

This edit's main(maybe I should not say "main", it totally is!) contributor is @yode. Without his help, this code will still need a stupid mask.......

Now this answer can correct the image at higher accuracy and have higher detection rate.

The result is like this~

[image: result 2]

This code requires only imgo and ker:

```
Inpaint[imgo, 
 Binarize[ColorSeparate[
   HighlightImage[
    imgo, {Red, Opacity@1, 
     Disk[#, 20] & /@ 
      ImageCorners@
       Binarize[
        ImageCorrelate[
         SelectComponents[ColorNegate@Binarize@imgo, 
          "PerimeterLength", 40 < # < 200 &], ker, 
         Mean@Abs@Flatten[#1 - #2] &], .2]}], "R"], .95]]
```

BTW: @yode is on his way to post a much more elegant, faster and wider appliable answer.

Comment: Thank you for reply. This procedures are very useful for me, and it will find place in my image manipulations. :)
But unfortunately, in this example, this does not lead to satisfying results. 
my run without mask, leads to following result [resultimage](http://imgur.com/iWefaOG)
The reasons are:
1) I'm unable to create masks `msk1`, because, there are too much variations of row spacings, and row heights, in texts.
2) it is impossible to create all variations of shaper in `ker`

Comment: I hope that this can be solved with topological and geometrical search of objects of desired shape across the image. But I have no idea how to start and which functions can be appropriate in this application.

Comment: `msk1` needn't be created with much care. Just use the drawing tools in Mathematica and There'll be a suggestion bar telling you how to create a mask. This act is simply for removing some unnecessary mis-detection. And for your second question, I think it's quite hard and the only way to do so is by adding more and more `ker` image by geometrical transforming our orignal `ker`. It it quite hard and needs extra time......

Comment: maybe I'll add something to automatically create this mask sometime later.

Answer (score 2):

Thank @Wjx, and especially @yode for idea. I refined selector conditions a bit. I built function that check angle of feature from it's `MinimalBoundingBox`. Also elongation is calculated from `MinimalBoundingBox`. There are also linear constraints, as two line inequalities, that restricts elongation and one of `MinimalBoundingBox` sides.

```
imx = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRUEw.jpg"]
angle = 25;
perlen = {35, 230};

checkangle=(If[! 
  Chop[Abs@{#[[1,1]]-#[[2,1]],#[[1,2]]-#[[2,2]]} - 
     Reverse[Abs@{#[[2,1]]-#[[3,1]],#[[2,2]]-#[[3,2]]}], 
    10^-6]==={0,0}
 , If[
   EuclideanDistance[{#[[1,1]],#[[1,2]]},{#[[2,1]],#[[2,2]]}] > 
    EuclideanDistance[{#[[3,1]],#[[3,2]]},{#[[2,1]],#[[2,2]]}]
   ,N@#/Degree&@ArcTan[Abs[#[[2,1]]-#[[1,1]]],Abs[#[[2,2]]-#[[1,2]]]]
   ,N@#/Degree&@ArcTan[Abs[#[[2,1]]-#[[3,1]]],Abs[#[[2,2]]-#[[3,2]]]]
   ] < angle
 , False
 ] &@N@{{#[[1,1]],#[[1,2]]},{#[[2,1]],#[[2,2]]},{#[[3,1]],#[[3,2]]}}) &;

Inpaint[imx
 , Dilation[
  SelectComponents[
   (ColorNegate@Binarize[imx, .8])
   , {"MinimalBoundingBox", "PerimeterLength"}
   , perlen[[1]] < #2 < perlen[[2]]
     && checkangle@#1
     && Function[{e, 
        x}, ! (((x < -16.8 + 80*e) && (x > 69 - 50*e)) || (e < 
            0.2))] @@ (Function[{y, x}, {1 - y/x, x}] @@ (Sequence @@@
           Sort[EuclideanDistance @@@ 
            Partition[#1[[1 ;; 3]], 2, 1]])) &
   ], 1]
 , Method -> "TextureSynthesis"
 ]
```

The result is:

[image: resultimage]

( by the way, I would like to replace `Function[{y,x}, {1-y/x,x}]` with pure function )